# Frequency Distribution Plot of Document Term Matrix

Tags: r, tm

I have created a document term matrix that looks something like this:

```
inspect(dtm[1:4,1:6])

              allowed allowing almost alone companyunder companywide 
Doc1.txt         1      1         1     0       1             0
Doc2.txt         0      1         1     0       1             1
Doc3.txt         0      0         0     1       0             1
Doc4.txt         1      0         1     0       1             1
```

After taking it's column sum it gives me.

```
colSums(dtm)

 allowed          2
 allowing         2 
 almost           3
 alone            1
 companyunder     3
 companywide      3
```

This essentially indicates that these words are found in how many documents (for eg allowed 2 tells me that allowed is found in two documents.).

I'm having difficulty in creating a frequency distribution plot which will have x-axis as the document number and y-axis as the number of words the document contains.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dtm = array(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1),dim=c(4,6))
dimnames(dtm) = list(c("Doc1","Doc2","Doc3","Doc4"),c("allowed","allowing","almost","alone","companyunder","companywide"))
print(dtm)
plot(rowSums(dtm))
```

Comment: Something like that. But my corpus as 184 documents and 39825 terms. So if I try to plot rowSums it gives me an error 'Error in rowSums(dtm) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions'

Comment: You're not using plot, are you?

Comment: Oh, I am. I've realized my mistake. But I can't seem to solve it.

Comment: You have to give more details if you want some help. Could you tell me the exact plotting command that you use?

Comment: So I'm doing dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus). Then rowSums(dtm). Which I think is the problem. Because it's giving me 'Error in rowSums(dtm) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions'. So even if I try plot(rowSums(dtm)). It's giving me the same error

Comment: I don't know the first thing about DocumentTermMatrix objects, and I can't find satisfying doc. I can't find your syntax though. Anyway, can you do dim(dtm)? rowSums only works on 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Actually I figured out a way. I did dtmmat<-as.matrix(dtm). And then tried rowSums(dtm) which works correctly. I then used plot(rowSums(dtmmat)) and it's working.